# sqldeveloper error message: the network adapter couldnt establish the connection vendor code 20

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I had made connection to the local oracle database through sqldeveloper on my system. Suddenly the power went down and I had to restart the system. Now, when I am trying to connect to the remote oracle database, it's throwing an error message:

SID: orcl , host:localhost , username: hr , password: hr

The Network adapter could not establish the connection. Vendor code 20

Can anyone help me solving this problem.

Comment: Make sure database is up and running. And do as `tnsping orcl` from command prompt.

Comment: @Polppan here is what i found                                                               
C:\Documents and Settings\New>tnsping orcl
TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 23-OCT-2
014 12:48:31

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
D:\app\New\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost
t)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener

Comment: It is always better to provide your results and code snippets in your question by editing it. From the tnsping results, apparently your database listener is down, you start your listener if your database is up.